# How can I set the old transformation after the animation has finished?

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform

I have a scene with several **triangles** on it with different colors and so on which the users can create when they touch the view. The **triangle** is placed where the user touched the view and is added to a **topView** (which is linked to a context menu but this is something different).

I want to apply the current transformation of my **triangle** after the animation has finished.
Right now it animates it 4 times and when the animation has finished it shrinks abrupt without an animation and places it not at the old position.

```
      let invertedTransform = topView.transform.inverted()
      let triangles = TriangleView()
      triangles.transform = invertedTransform
      topView.addsubview(triangles)
      triangleArray.append(triangles)

      for triangle in triangleArray {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat,.autoreverse], animations: {
        UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(4)
           triangle.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2.4, y: 2.4) }, completion: { done in
           if done {
             triangle.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
            }
         })
      }
```

I think the mistake is in the **completion** part.The **.autoreverse** option is doing the reverse animation fine but when it finishes it doesn't shrink back.

How can I save my the current transformation of my **triangle** and set a pulsating animation for it?

---

UPDATE

I forgot to mention that the every **triangle** has a **rotation** value which is stored in a database:

```
triangle.rotation.value
```

The default transformation which is indeed given through the **.identity** method is the **rotation value** 0. When a rotation is applied on a **triangle** object it should set it back to the original value which is stored in the **triangle** object above:

```
let triangles = TriangleView(x: touchpoint.x, y: touchpoint.y, rotation: triangle.rotation.value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The completion part should probably be (not enough code provided to test it):

```
if done {
    triangle.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity // or just .identity
}
```

That sets the transform state back to "original" / "no transform".

---

**Edit**

If your object already has a transform, you'll need to either save it or re-create it.

So, for example, add a property to your `TriangleView` that saves its "initial" state:

```
var initialTransform: CGAffineTransform!
```

When you init the view and setup the rotation transform, save that:

```
self.initialTransform = self.transform
```

Your animation completion then becomes:

```
if done {
    triangle.transform = triangle.initialTransform
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I forgot to mention that every **triangle** has a rotation value. Every object can be rotated by 360° ( 15° every time the user long press a triangle after its created). This value is stored inside of the **triangle** object. I updated my answer. So the **.identity** method only gives me the rotation value of 0

Comment: Thank you! This did it.